# Fixed Size Queue

Tags: c++, c++11, queue

I have written a simple fixed size queue and am looking to get feedback on best practices. Specifically, handling unintended behaviors e.g. construct with negative size. This is not for a specific project but more of practicing good coding skills. I tried to follow the Google Code Style.

I am also looking for feedback on code coverage and unit tests.

Note: I realize that the pop function that I implemented is different that the std::queue and I don't have front and back functions.

Full code including CMakeLists.txt is [here](https://github.com/kosaris/fixed_size_queue)

**fixed_size_queue.h**

```
#ifndef FIXED_SIZE_QUEUE_H
#define FIXED_SIZE_QUEUE_H
#include "iostream"

template <class T> class FixedSizeQueue {
private:
  int size_;
  int start_index_;
  int end_index_;
  T *start_p_;

public:
  // Must be constructed with an argument
  FixedSizeQueue(int size);

  ~FixedSizeQueue();

  bool isEmpty() const;

  bool isFull() const;

  // push a single element to the queue
  // returns false if queue is full
  // returns true otherwise
  bool push(const T& data); 

  // pop a single element from the queue
  // returns the element on success
  // throws a logic_error exception if attempting to pop from an empty queue (undefined behavior)
  T pop();

  void print() const;
};

#endif
```

**fixed_size_queue.cpp**

```
#include "fixed_size_queue.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "stdexcept"

template <class T>
FixedSizeQueue<T>::FixedSizeQueue(int size)
    : size_(size), start_index_(-1), end_index_(-1), start_p_(new T[size]) {}

template <class T> FixedSizeQueue<T>::~FixedSizeQueue() { delete[] start_p_; }

template <class T> bool FixedSizeQueue<T>::isEmpty() const {
  return start_index_ == -1;
}

template <class T> bool FixedSizeQueue<T>::isFull() const {
  if ((end_index_ + 1 == start_index_) ||
      (start_index_ == 0 && end_index_ == size_ - 1))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

template <class T> bool FixedSizeQueue<T>::push(const T &data) {
  if (isFull()) {
    return false;
  } else if (isEmpty()) {
    start_index_ = 0;
    end_index_ = 0;
    start_p_[end_index_] = data;
  } else if (end_index_ != size_ - 1) {
    start_p_[++end_index_] = data;
  } else {
    end_index_ = 0;
    start_p_[end_index_] = data;
  }
  return true;
}

template <class T> T FixedSizeQueue<T>::pop() {
  if (isEmpty()) {
    throw std::logic_error("Empty Queue");
  } else if (start_index_ == end_index_) {
    T temp = start_p_[end_index_];
    start_index_ = -1;
    end_index_ = -1;
    return temp;
  } else if (start_index_ == size_ - 1) {
    start_index_ = 0;
    return start_p_[size_ - 1];
  } else {
    return start_p_[start_index_++];
  }
}

template <class T> void FixedSizeQueue<T>::print() const {
  if (start_index_ == -1) {
    std::cout << "Empty Queue" << std::endl;
  } else {
    for (int i = start_index_; i != end_index_;) {
      std::cout << start_p_[i] << "\t";
      if (i == size_ - 1) {
        i = 0;
      } else {
        ++i;
      }
    }
    std::cout << start_p_[end_index_];
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

TEST(QueueTest, PushAndPopWithoutWrapping) {
  FixedSizeQueue<int> queue(5);
  queue.push(1);
  queue.push(2);
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.pop(), testing::Eq(1));
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.pop(), testing::Eq(2));
}

TEST(QueueTest, PushAndPopWithWrapping) {
  FixedSizeQueue<int> queue(3);
  queue.push(1);
  queue.push(2);
  queue.push(3);
  queue.pop();
  queue.push(4);
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.pop(), testing::Eq(2));
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.pop(), testing::Eq(3));
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.pop(), testing::Eq(4));
}

TEST(QueueTest, PushToAFullQueue) {
  FixedSizeQueue<int> queue(3);
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.push(1), testing::Eq(true));
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.push(2), testing::Eq(true));
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.push(3), testing::Eq(true));
  ASSERT_THAT(queue.push(4), testing::Eq(false));
}

TEST(QueueTest, PopFromEmptyQueue) {
  FixedSizeQueue<int> queue(3);
  try {
    queue.pop();
  } catch (std::logic_error &e) {
    EXPECT_STREQ("Empty Queue", e.what());
  }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since I ended up implementing a stack instead of a queue. However, my suggestion about [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) is something you should look into.

Comment: *size* should be `unsigned`, or (even better) `size_t`. FixedSizeQueue(-1) does really bad things.

Comment: @jvb, new expression will cast it anyway, so it would just overflow ram and hopefully system will kill it. Though I'm not sure if integer promotion will kick in, in which case it will just allocate huge amount of memory, but not enough to overflow.

Comment: @jvb I converted `size_` to be of type *size_t_* but I want `start_index_` to remain an _int_ so that I can assign -1 to it when the queue is empty. This causes a warning when doing `start_index_ == size_ -1` comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions. I can do `start_index_ == (int)size_ -1` instead. Can you recommend a better way? of course going to a `std::vector` implementation as suggested below will solve this altogether.

Comment: @Sam You could maybe use a hypothetical `unsigned count` (current fill level) instead of `end_index`? Both `isEmpty` and `isFull` implementations would become easier, but you would have to replace `end_index` with `start_index+count`...

Comment: Any thoughts on unit tests are welcome. What should be the extent and code coverage? Any feedback on the tests that are already implemented?

Answer (score 4):

Please consider using <strike>`std::array`</strike>`std::vector` (as @Incomputable noted) for storage. If you insist on using `new`, you *have* to add an own copy constructor (or to disable the compiler-generated copy constructor).

If you copy a `FixedSizeQueue`, the member pointer `*start_p_` will be copied, too... and both instances will operate *on the same memory*, which clearly is not the intended behavior. Even worse, when the destructor is called on one instance, it will render the other instance in an unpredictable state (as it will `delete[]` the shared memory) and its destructor call will probably crash.

Comment: `std::array` is unusable here due to runtime size.

Comment: @Incomputable `std::array` can be used with variable size determined at runtime, but the size cannot be *changed after allocation* at runtime... exactly the same as with `new[]`.

Comment: the only place to supply the size would be constructor, but there is none that takes any integer, and default one is implicitly declared. The only option is template argument, which strictly should be supplied during compilation time. Unless one can implement type erasure and gigantic switch statement.

Comment: @Incomputable I see what you mean. Let's simply use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

#### The interface to `pop()`

Let's start with your definition of `pop`. As clumsy as it is, there *is* a reason that `pop_back` (and `pop_front`) don't return the popped item. As you've defined it, `pop` has a serious problem with exception safety. If you pop the item from the queue, then it throws an exception while you're copying it to the caller, you've lost the item you just popped--it's no longer in the queue *and* the caller hasn't received it either.

It is possible to define a `pop` that's at least somewhat less clumsy (IMO) than that used by `std::deque` and such.

```
void pop(T &dest) {
    dest = /* front of queue */;
    /* remove front item from queue */
}
```

This way, one of two things happens: either the pop succeeds completely, or else it has no effect.

#### Memory Allocation

Right now, you're using `new T[size]` to allocate your storage. That's fine for something like `int`, but it's a serious problem if you want your queue to store things that can be moved but not assigned, or items that don't support default construction.

Most containers use `operator new` to allocate "raw" memory, then use placement new to create items in that space.

#### Assymetry

Right now, `push` signals failure (at least part of the time) by returning `false` but `pop` signals failure by throwing an exception. It's usually cleaner to choose one or the other and stick to it throughout the design.

Comment: actually the item is still in the queue, but user will not be able to reach it

Comment: @Incomputable: Technically yes--but inaccessible is as good as gone.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Is it safe to generalize this and say: A member function that cannot be declared a const member function should not return a variable? Or it this statement too broad? If I understood correctly the issue is that the copy to caller might throw and exception and we end up with no return value but the function has had its effect.

Comment: @Sam: Some people take the notion of single responsibility to the point that they figure a member should *either* return a value, *or* change a value, but never both. While I respect the underlying idea, it doesn't seem (to me) that it necessarily leads to better designs (and for many compare-exchange sorts of atomic operations, it just doesn't work at all).